# How do I get my NancyFX unit tests to run my validation?

Tags: unit-testing, nancy, fluentvalidation

I'm using NancyFX with FluentValidation, as documented at https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Nancy-and-Validation. My web app is running fine and validation is working perfectly, but when I try to unit test any of the modules that use validation, I'm getting an error

```
Nancy.Validation.ModelValidationException : No model validator factory could be located.
Please ensure that you have an appropriate validation package installed, such as 
one of the Nancy.Validation packages.
```

I've verified that my unit test project has references to the  `Nancy.Validation.FluentValidation` and `FluentValidation` assemblies.

My test code looks like this:

```
public class ArticleModuleTests {
    private Browser browser;
    private IDatabase db;

    const int USER_ID = 123;
    const int ARTICLE_ID = 456;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp() {
        var user = new User { Username = "test", Id = USER_ID };
        db = A.Fake<IDatabase>();
        browser = new Browser(with => {
        with.Module<ArticleModule>();
        with.RequestStartup((container, pipelines, context) => context.CurrentUser = user);
        with.Dependency(db);
        });
    }

    [Test]
    public void User_Can_Publish_Article() {
        var article = new { title = "Test" };
        var result = browser.Post($"/users/{USER_ID}/articles", with => {
            with.HttpRequest();
            with.Body(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(article));
        });
        result.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

My module code is:

```
public class ArticlesModule : NancyModule {
    private IDatabase database;
    public ArticlesModule(IDatabase db) {
        this.database = db;
        Post["/users/{id:int}/articles"] = args => PostArticle(args.id);
    }

    private dynamic PostArticle(int userId) {
        var article = this.Bind<Article>();
        var validation = this.Validate(article);
        if (!validation.IsValid) return Negotiate.WithModel(validation).WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        database.CreateArticle(userId, article);
        return NegotiatorExtensions.WithModel(Negotiate, result)
            .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Created)
            .WithHeader("Location", $"http://whatever/users/{userId}/articles/{article.Id}");
    }
}
```

and my validation class is:

```
 public class ArticleValidator : AbstractValidator<Article> {
    public ArticleValidator() {            
        RuleFor(article => article.Title)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("The \"title\" property is required");
        RuleFor(article => article.Title)
            .Length(2, 50)
            .WithMessage("The \"title\" property must be between 2 and 50 characters");
    }
}
```

The [NancyFX docs](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Nancy-and-Validation) say "Create a validation class... There is no need to register it anywhere as it is automatically detected." - but I'm guessing whatever automatic detection is wired up isn't firing for a unit test project. I'm building on .NET 4.5.2 and using NCrunch as my test runner; what do I need to do to get my test code to pick up the same validation classes as my application modules?

Comment: Nancy.Validation.FluentValidation needs to be installed in the unit test project unfortunately

Comment: It was installed, but NCrunch was omitting it when building the test project. I've updated https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Nancy-and-Validation with a note to this effect.

Answer (score 5):

OK, turns out that because NancyFX detects and instantiates validation classes automatically, there's no explicit references in my code to `Nancy.Validation.FluentValidation`, and so NCrunch is omitting this assembly when building my test project. Setting "Copy referenced assemblies to workspace" in the NCrunch project settings fixed it.